# Show banner from admob free in Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, admob

I am trying to show my banner from Admob free in my Ionic 3 app. I have followed the instructions of the Ionic documentation on the following link:

Link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/

This is my code for my banner in homepage.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig} from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public admob: AdMobFree) {
    this.showInterstitialAds();
  }

  showInterstitialAds() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      id: 'ca-app-pub-id',
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
    };
    this.admob.interstitial.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admob.interstitial.prepare()
      .then(() => {
        this.admob.interstitial.show()
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

When I run the app it doesn't show my banner. I have no addblock extension installed and I have made an admob account on Google. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the app it doesn't show my banner. **I have no addblock
>   extension installed** and I have made an admob account on Google. What
>   am I doing wrong?

admob native plugin only works on a device.

Comment: Ah I have to install something like a emulator?

Comment: correct, almost all of the plugins you will find won't work on the browser.